# trying to place content from file in a table

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have information that has been written to a file and I am trying to output it via a servlet into a table but it is not going into the table, rather it is just being written on the page.

Here is the code where I am opening the file that is tab deliminated so I need to pull in each row and place the content between tabs in its own cell but it is just printing above the table.

```
     // Create a file reader that to read the file
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

    // Create the buffered reader stream
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    // Print the table header for of the survey results
    out.println("<label> Here are the results of the survey up to now: </label>");
    out.println("<table border='1'>");
    out.println("<tr><th><b>Date/time</b></th>");
    out.println("<th><b>Animal</b></th>");
    out.println("<th><b>Relative</b></th>");
    out.println("<th><b>Color</b></th>");
    out.println("<th><b>Tv Show</b></th>");
    out.println("<th><b>Actor</b></th></tr>");

    // Print each record
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split("\t");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (String value : values) {
            out.println("<td>" + value + "</td");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you to write the presentation logic in JSP/HTML rather than mixing business logic with user interface in the Servlet.

Simply move the HTML code in JSP and pass the list from the Servlet to JSP and iterate it in JSP using [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net) & JSP Expression Language.

**Note:** Don't forget to close the resources in Servlet, either use `try-finally` block or use [Java 7 The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

---

#### Sample code:

Servlet: (*using Java 7 The try-with-resources Statement*)

```
try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file)){
    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)){
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\t");
            list.add(values);
        }

        request.setAttribute("list", list);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("xyz.jsp").forward(request, response);  
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<label> Here are the results of the survey up to now: </label>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th><b>Date/time</b></th>
        <th><b>Animal</b></th>
        <th><b>Relative</b></th>
        <th><b>Color</b></th>
        <th><b>Tv Show</b></th>
        <th><b>Actor</b></th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="array">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${array}" var="item">
                <td>${item}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: That does look like a great alternative, in this case I need it to be in the servlet.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand it. Why it's not an alternative? Can you explain a bit more, please? Please have a look at [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that is discovered by experts.